# Mutex does not work as I expect. What is my mistake?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was trying to figure out the data race theme, and I made this code. Here we work with the shared element `wnd`. I thought that by putting lock in the while loop, I would prohibit the `th1` thread from working with `wnd`, but this did not happen and I see an unobstructed output of the `th1` thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
     bool wnd = true;
     std::mutex mutex;
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex, std::defer_lock);


     std::thread th1([&]() {
         int i = 0;
         while (true)
         {
             ++i;
             if (wnd)
                 std::cout << i << "   WND TRUE" << std::endl;
             else
                 std::cout << i << "   WND FALSE" << std::endl;
             std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
         }
     });

     
     while (true)
     {
        lock.lock();
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
         if (wnd)
             wnd = false;
         else
             wnd = true;
        lock.unlock();

         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
     }
     
     th1.join();
     return 0;
}
```

To tell the truth, I was hoping to see that the `th1` thread stops printing for 2+-seconds at a time when the main thread is inside the lock section.

Comment: You're only locking the main thread. The other thread can't know the main thread is locked. Synchronization is about two threads sharing one lock and each asking for exclusive access to it.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Understood. how can I synchronize the data in the case I presented?

Comment: by locking the mutex in your other thread?

Comment: You need to lock/unlock in the `th1` thread also, which is usually done around the access to the shared data.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Using the same mutex?

Comment: Yes. Mutex is a mutually exclusive flag. When you lock you tell it that you're accessing the resource. All other threads that are trying to lock (in order to access the resource) will have to wait until the mutex is unlocked. That's how the synchronization between the threads works in order to ensure exclusive access to data in order to prevent data races.

Comment: @Artem.rtv Not to be rude or anything, but if you need to ask that question you should probably start by going through some basic tutorial or book on the subject.

Comment: @super I understand your dissatisfaction, but I have not found a case like this in books and video tutorials. They mainly consider the topic of using, for example, a method in two threads. And I want to deal with this option.I thought this resource was created to help. I made a reproducible example and fully described my problem. If you do not have the desire to suggest an answer, then you can pass by.

Comment: @super Or can only super-professionals with extraordinary questions use this resource? I didn't see this in the community rules

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Sorry to bother you. Help me one last time. I supplemented the code by adding lock\unlock to the first thread, but I get an error.I updated the code in the description

Comment: @Artem.rtv Not really sure what you mean. This is pretty much the most basic example of mutex usage you can have. One shared variable. One mutex. I doubt that you can find any tutorial out there that **doesn't** cover this case. If you have a look at [ask], the very first thing is search and research.

Comment: I reverted your edit. Sorry, But these questions are archived so that other people who have similar problems might be able to find them. If you ask other questions in the future, please don't fix your code examples to show the solved problem. Leave the problem as-is so that other people will be able to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the mutex and specially `std::unique_lock` properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
     bool wnd = true;
     std::mutex mutex;

     std::thread th1{[&]() {
         for (int i = 0; i<10000; ++i)
         {   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
             std::cout << i << "\tWND\t " << std::boolalpha << wnd << std::endl;
         };
     }};

     for (int i = 0; i<30; ++i)
     {   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
         wnd = !wnd;
     }; 

     th1.join();
}
```

[`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) uses its constructor operand as a resource whose acquisition is `lock` and release is `unlock`. It is designed to use [`RAII`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) as a means of guaranteeing correct lock/unlock sequences on mutexes. a defered lock only means the mutex is not locked at the begining of lifespan of the `std::unique_lock` and it is not the usual use case. You can manually lock/unlock the mutex, but that generally leads to less maintainable, more error-prone code.
Keep in mind that if the threads involved are not racing over the ownership of the mutex, neither waits for the other; in your original prorgram, the worker thread did not touch the mutex. But in the program above, both threads are competing to lock the mutex; winner gets a chance to continue what he wants, and the loser has to wait until the mutex is unlocked - so that he can take its ownership.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured it out. I had to create 2 different unique_lock elements with the same mutex element

Comment: It is important to know why you need two. A mutex is like a restroom. If one enters(aquires/locks), the others must wait till he exits(releases/unlocks). unique_lock is like some automated electronic detector that must see who entered the restroom.

Comment: Fwiw, this can race the mutex relatch. There is no guarantee the scheduler will give up the time slice on release of the mutex before coming around again in the lower for-loop and reacquiring it. My rig, macOS 12.3.1 using clang 13.1.6 in both debug and release mode this will stall a full 60 seconds, then dump 10000 lines of wnd true, then exit.

Comment: @WhozCraig
Let's keep things simple. That is not what I do in production. A detailed discussion of parallelism might distract attention from the main question. I just wanted the program to have a decent end, and no further complication. The proper program however could use `std::jthread`(instead of `std::thread`) along with `std::stop_token`. But that would be a distraction for now.